# Forward packets to one address to local application listening on different address

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have a computer with two interfaces eth1 with 10.223.75.53 and eth2 with 192.168.1.1. Eth2 does not have network cable connected but there is application listening on 192.168.1.1 on port 5000 lets assume this application is netcat. Eth1 is connected to network. Some application on the network will make tcp connection with 10.223.75.53:5000 so I want to redirect all traffic on 10.223.75.53:5000 to 192.168.1.1:5000.

I tried following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
```

Launched server:

```
netcat -l -p 5000 192.168.1.1 # local server
```

and tried to communicate:

```
netcat 10.223.75.53 5000
```

Server crashed with information:

```
netcat -l -p 5000 192.168.1.1
invalid connection to [10.223.75.53] from (UNKNOWN) [10.223.75.53] 49116
```

And client just exited.

My routing table is:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.223.75.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
10.223.75.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2

$ ip rule ls
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

I do not understand what is wrong with my rule.

Comment: Can you post your routing table (output of `route -n`)? Do you have any routing rules (output of `ip rule ls`)?

Comment: @Khaled I have added table to the post.